# MonoGame audio format

Tags: xna, monogame, monotouch

MP4 AAC is a well supported playback format [according to the docs](https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/wiki/Content-Build-Pipeline), but the MonoGame content project only seems to compile MP3/WAV/WMA formats. I tried to put raw aac files in my android game but the content manager wouldnt load them, only raw wav files work, but they are large in size. I would like to know how to load aac or ogg audio files.

Comment: What specific problem did you run into, when you say `content manager wouldnt load them`? Did you get an exception of some sort?

Comment: @ashes999 Well there are only Content Importer options for mp3/wav/wma, no aac or ogg importer. If I try to compile aac with importer set to wma for example, I get a 'Failed to open file. Ensure the file is a valid audio file and is not DRM protected.' error. So my question is if its possible to compile aac and ogg, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Loading OGG files should work the same as MP3s. I have this working in my own games, as simply as (pseudocode):

```
var sound = ContentManager.Load("blah.ogg");
sound.Play();
```

The issue I ran into is that some devices (especially older ones) may not always work with every kind of file format.